# Generate code for different requests types from config

Tags: go, go-generate

I have an app that makes a lot of requests to different urls.
Each of them have different request & response structure.

Configurations of the requests types located in Mysql databse.

It contains next data:

- URL
- Method
- Query params
- Body params
- Headers
- Response structure

So while before I was using Node.js for this things it was easy to make solution for this.

But with Go I see only way in using reflect package for this. But reflect harms performance of the app.

Is there a simple way to generate code for this?

Example of request config:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Req1",
  url: "http://example.com",
  query: [
    {name: "user_id", source: "user", value: "id" },
    {name: "user_ip", source: "user", value: "ip" },
    {name: "token", source: "const", value: "xxx" },
  ],
  headers: [
   {name: "Accept-Language", source: "user", value: "language"}
  ],
  body: [
    {"name": "user.ua", "user", "ua"}
  ]
}
```

User example:

```
{
  ip: "127.0.0.1",
  id: "123",
  ua: "User Agent...",
  "language": "en"
}
```

And in the output should be made next request:

```
URL: http://example.com?user_id=123&user_ip=127.0.0.1&token=xxx
Headers:
{
  Accept-Language: en
}
Body:
{
  user: {
    ua: "User Agent..."
  }
}
```

In body might be used path of the param.

Is there a tool for automatically generating this type of code?

Comment: You can probably translate your JS code to Go. I don't see anything in the question that requires code generation or reflect.

Comment: What is your input? If it is json files, there are several packages (like https://github.com/mholt/json-to-go) that can help you. Otherwise you'll have to type them.

Comment: @CeriseLimón there is different request / response structures. And there is like 50 different, I don't want to write manually code for each type of request. Without reflect I don't see a way to set some "object" value by path. And I know that for better performance it's better to use defined types, so I need to generate those types dynamically. And also the code that will choose the proper type dynamically.

Comment: Don't create a type for each request.  Use map[string]interface{}, []interface{} and so on.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois my input is the id of request type, and the user data. Based on this need to build request & parse it's response. I have like 50 types of different requests. Also I know that for better performance it's better to use defined types. So I want to generate those types dinamically & I need to dynamically generate code that will take proper types for given request.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, but it will degrade the performance as far as I know. And there will be billions of requests. Performance must be top notch. That why I switching from Node.js to Go.

Comment: Unless you already have the evidence, you should not assume that slinging data in and out of request specific types is faster than using a small set of common types.

Comment: I meant what input do you have for the generation, not for the program. Is it only a JS code? If so you should take your structures and extract them to json and use the project I sent the link of before. Otherwise you can generate models and even http server/client from a Swagger with https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger. Anyways you need a well-formated input for your generation, otherwise you'll have to do it with your fingers.